# Datepicker with JQuery 1.11.2

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I followed a tutorial exactly on how to create bootstrap datepicker but i still can't get the job done. Kindly assist me with a solution. Thank you

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../datepicker/css/datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="../datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="../datepicker/js/main.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="well">
        Date of Birth : <input class="datepicker" type="text" name="date">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Could you provide more information? If you open Developer Tools (in Chrome, Firefox and IE have similar), and then click on "Console" - it should (hopefully) give you some form of error message (something like "datepicker() is not an assigned function or call".) Update your question with the results. :)

Comment: @jeffcarey when i click in the input textbox, the calendar should pop up but it doesn't

Comment: @AlexMulchinock there is no error showing up in the console

Comment: @Beginner - that's interesting. I tested this on JS fiddle last night, and was seeing console errors. I'll have another play later on this evening, and let you know what I find.

Comment: @AlexMulchinock . thanks and i will be waiting for your help